# Expo React Native Fetch API throw "Network request failed" error when turning a base64 image into blob

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I wrote this code:

```
export default (base64, type = 'application/octet-stream') =>
    fetch(`data:${type};base64,${base64}`).then((res) => res.blob());
```

in order to transform my base64 image into blob.

my base64 image is coming from this function:

```
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

const openImagePickerAsync = async () => {
   ...
   const pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
        base64: true
    });
   ...
}
```

this library returns me the base64 image that it did grab from the camera roll,
so I can use on the first function I sent to turn into a blob.

the problem is that when I try to do this from my android real device, this fetch api throws "Network request failed" error.

advices? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact issue only happening on android. I originally was doing the following:

```
export const systemFileToBlobAsync = async (fileUrl: string, fileType: FileMimeTypeValue) => {
  var fileString = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(fileUrl, { encoding: 'base64' });
  const fetchResponse = await fetch(`data:${fileType};base64,${fileString}`);
  return await fetchResponse.blob();
};
```

That code was working perfectly in iOS.

To fix my issue I just used the fileUrl and it worked perfectly. I did also test this solution on iOS and it worked there as well.

So the working solution for me was:

```
export const systemFileToBlobAsync = async (fileUrl: string) => {
  const fetchResponse = await fetch(fileUrl);
  return await fetchResponse.blob();
};
```

Hope that helps someone else that might run into this issue.